# Does Probe() method in linux need to be re-entrant?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

There is a function which will be called from two different platform drivers. I want to know whether there is any chance for platform driver core of linux to call probe() of two different devices concurrently? If yes then the common function being called from these two probe()'s should be designed re-entrant.

Comment: It would have been a lot nicer if you told us what exactly `probe()` function you are talking about. PCIe? USB? There are many.

Comment: The probe() i mentioned is for camera sensor's and they are registered both as platform and i2c devices. @VladLazarenko

Comment: I would think that if your probe() function needs memory, it has the ability to be put to sleep during that request, so the code should indeed be designed to be re-entrant.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, every function of kernel must be re-entrant. Maybe your function does not need to be re-entrant now but, who know what happens in future?

`probe` functions calls, more specifically, AFAIK, they are serialized during bus enumeration at start. However, some people may try to parallelize them in order to get faster boot.

In add, we can also imagine a situation where two devices are plugged simultaneously. Bus driver may call `probe` function a second time while first is not yet finished.

My opinion is your probe function have to be re-entrant.